# No price result found for Flight Cheapest Date Search API

Tags: api, amadeus

I'm testing the "Flight Cheapest Date Search" API of self-service. I see that `however not all locations are available` in the Introduction of this API. But it seems that most of locations don't work, even for the very popular locations, for example: `paris-barcelona`, `madrid-london`, `london-san francisco` etc.

I got always this error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "code": 141,
      "title": "SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED",
      "detail": "No price result found for requested destination"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wonder if that's because the testing environment? And it works much better in the production?

Then if I can find the supported locations somewhere? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test environment is based on a subset of the production data. In case you want to see what data is available in test please refer to the test [data collection on GitHub](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection)

The production environment offers much higher coverage than test.
If you are done prototyping your application and want to access to live production data, you can follow the "[Moving to production guide](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/developer-guides/blob/master/guides/production.md)", it offers easy to follow instructions on how to move to production. Please keep in mind we also provide free monthly quotas in the production environment, to allow you to explore the data available.

Regarding this specific API, Flight Cheapest Date Search and Flight Inspiration Search are inspirational APIs, we build a cache on pre-selected sets of origin-destination so even in production you will not find every route, for this, you need to use the live search Flight Offers Search. We are actually working on a new version of the cache that will offer better data in test and in production.